# postgres substring trigger issue

Tags: postgresql, triggers, substring

have issue using substring with postgres trigger
here is the trigger i used

```
CREATE FUNCTION TRIGGER1() RETURNS trigger AS $autouuid$
BEGIN

    update test_points.scada_rtu i
    set dummy #field_name
    = upper(substr (NEW.city_name, 1, 2) || right (NEW.city_name, 1) || '-' || substr  (NEW.phase_name, 1, 2) || right (NEW.phase_name, 1) || '-' || substr (NEW.area_name, 1, 3) || '-' || 
            substr(NEW.name, 1, 2) || right (NEW.name, 1) || '-' || substr (NEW.rtu_model, 1, 2) || right (NEW.rtu_model, 1)) 
    WHERE i.id = OLD.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$autouuid$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER autouuid_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test_points.scada_rtu
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.TRIGGER1();
```

Comment: What is the error or problem you have? And why use an UPDATE? You can simply assign the value `new.dummy := upper(....)`

Comment: does postgresXl support trigger ?

Comment: i added error message

Comment: Please, use plain text instead of images outside of Stackoverflow.

Comment: By the way, this trigger and trigger function won't work: You update a table, the trigger fires, does another update, the trigger fires because of that update, it does another update, another trigger, etc. Endless loop. Just assign the correct value and don't do the update.

Comment: 1) Follow @FrankHeikens advice to avoid the recursion that is coming your way if you get the function to work. 2) The error is for a different version of the function. One where you had `...new.dummy=...`. As the error is telling you the `test_points.scada_rtu` table has no `new` column. `NEW` only exists  as a record type inside the trigger function.

Comment: really thanks for your help guys <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION TRIGGER1() RETURNS trigger AS $autouuid$
BEGIN
    NEW.dummy=upper(
                concat_ws('-',
                    regexp_replace(NEW.city_name,   '^(..).*(.)$',  '\1\2'),
                    regexp_replace(NEW.phase_name,  '^(..).*(.)$',  '\1\2'),
                    regexp_replace(NEW.name,        '^(..).*(.)$',  '\1\2'), 
                    regexp_replace(NEW.rtu_model,   '^(..).*(.)$',  '\1\2')
                )
              ); 
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$autouuid$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER autouuid_update BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON test_points.scada_rtu
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.TRIGGER1();
```

1. As pointed out by [@a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), you can assign the new values to `NEW` record directly, without issuing a new update.
2. Issuing a new update from a function triggered on updates makes it call itself, putting you in an infinite loop, as noted by [@Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens).
3. Direct assignment to [`record`-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS) variable `NEW` will solve your problem, because it'll operate within trigger's context where [trigger's special variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html) are visible. Your error is caused by the fact your update query thinks it's a reference to one of the target table's columns, ignoring the variable. [@Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver)
4. You don't need to repeatedly concatenate and manually add the separator each time using `||`. [`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html#:%7E:text=concat_ws%20(%20sep%20text,22)%20%E2%86%92%20abcde%2C2%2C22) does both of these things for you, also ignoring `NULL` values.
5. Getting the first two characters and the last character of a string can also be done with a single [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html#:%7E:text=regexp_replace%20(%20string%20text,a.%27%2C%20%27M%27)%20%E2%86%92%20ThM).
6. `#comment` is not a valid PL/pgSQL comment. Use `--comment` for single-line end-of-line or `/*comment*/` for multi-line, mid-line comments. Your comments will be saved with the function definition and visible whenever someone looks it up.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that valuable information it helped a lot Thank you